# LazyInitializationException when collection is loaded in a BeanItemContainer

Tags: hibernate, vaadin

I'm building a CRUD view for my jpa entities. Once I retrieved the instances of my entity with a jpa container each time I select the one instance I have to load the collection that is lazy initialized (I load it in a BeanItemContainer). So I did the following:

```
                BeanItemContainer<ModelItem> beans =
                    new BeanItemContainer<ModelItem>(ModelItem.class);

            Property property = item.getItemProperty(propertyID);


            if (property.getType().equals(Collection.class)){
                beans.addAll((Collection<? extends ModelItem>) property.getValue());
            }

            Class<? super ModelItem> clazz = beans.getBeanType();

            PropertyDescriptor properties[]=PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(clazz);

            ArrayList<Object> tablePropertiesList=new ArrayList<Object>();

            for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : properties) {
                if (!(propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType().equals(Collection.class)) && !(propertyDescriptor.getName().equals("class"))){
                    tablePropertiesList.add(propertyDescriptor.getName()); 
                }
            }

            Object tableProperties[]=transform(tablePropertiesList);

            Table currentTable = collections.get(propertyID);
            currentTable.setContainerDataSource(beans);
            currentTable.setVisibleColumns(tableProperties);
```

In this case I get the LazyInitializationException

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.windy.server.model.core.UserModel.favoriteUsersTo, no session or session was closed
```

How can I solve this problem with vaadin framework?

PS I'm using Hibernate as JPA implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Hibernate lazy fetching relation upon access (e.g. Accessing "favoriteUsersTo" in your particular case) and there is no Hibernate Session available to do the fetching.

I suggest you look into using the [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/jpacontainer/) instead. It will handle the hibernate session for you.

Comment: JPAContainer is not available for free apparently. A suggestion for a free solution?

Comment: I found a solution, implement your own container and only select the attributes you want in `public static final Object[] NATURAL_COL_ORDER = new Object[] {
  "field1", "field2" };`